# MongoDB unique index across multiple subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, unique-index, subdocument

I have this document structure, the property "Name" must be unique across all documents, as shown above:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56686341d6389c004c689d5d"), 
    "Bosses" : {
        "B1" : {
            "_id" : NumberInt(1), 
            "Name" : "John"
        },
        "B2" : {
            "_id" : NumberInt(1), 
            "Name" : "Mary"
        }
    }
}

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56686341d6389c004c689d6f"), 
    "Bosses" : {
        "B1" : {
            "_id" : NumberInt(1), 
            "Name" : "Mary" // should throw an error
        }
    }
}
```

It's possible to create a unique index with this structure?

Comment: Maybe it help you 
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to create a unique index on `Bosses.Name`. But then, You'll have to change a little bit your schema. `Bosses` should be an array:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56686341d6389c004c689d6f"), 
    "Bosses" : [
        {
            "_id" : NumberInt(1), 
            "Name" : "Mary" // should throw an error
        }
    }
}
```

If you really need the `B1`, I suggest you add it into `Bosses` objects: "Code": "B1". But this might not be necessary, as you can access the index in your array by `...find({ "Bosses.0.Name" })`

Comment: I really need to keep the original structure due to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3326. I know this is not the best solution, but it avoids aways calls to the database twice when updating a boss.

Comment: Could you explain more the problem your your upsert? Maybe the community can help you to build your upsert in a different way.